# How do i get pass this error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. i am using React18

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is the code

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseForm";
import { editExpense, removeExpense } from '../actions/expenses';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
//import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";



function EditExpensePage (props){
 const { id } = useParams();
const navigate = useNavigate()
 return(
   <div>
           <ExpenseForm 
           expense={props.expense}
           onSubmit={(expense) =>{
             props.dispatch(editExpense(id,expense))
             navigate('/');
           }}
           />

         <button onClick={()=>{
          props.dispatch(removeExpense({id: props.expense.id}));
          navigate('/');
       }}>Remove</button>
         </div>

         
 );
};

function MapStateToProps(state){
 const { id } = useParams();
 return{
   expense: state.expenses.find((expense)=> expense.id ===  id)
 };
};

   

  export default connect(MapStateToProps)(EditExpensePage);
```

i am trying to edit an expense with an id so that it can render a component that has the edited item. so far everything is working but after editing the field the component doesnt rerender, it return an error on the console. this is the error  Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is you have used `useParams` inside `MapStateToProps` which you can not use inside `MapStateToProps`.
You can do something like this:

```
function MapStateToProps(state,ownProps){
 const { id } = ownProps.match.params;
 return{
   expense: state.expenses.find((expense)=> expense.id ===  id)
 };
};
```

Comment: thank you @Hiren pipariya, but this did not work, it says  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Params'). the version of react-router-dom am using is v6

Comment: you need to wrap your export with `withRouter`

Comment: ```export default compose(
  withRouter,              // params prop
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(EditExpensePage); ```

Comment: thank you so much for your effort @hiren pipariya. so i was able to fix the error by downgrading my react version to version 16 because react-dates doesnt seem to be working correctly with react version 18